# An integral from a physical problem

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I am working out some computations in Yang-Mills theory and, in order to find the potential, I have to compute the following integral
$$
   V(r)=\int_0^\infty dp\frac{p(a+bp^2)}{cp^4+dp^2+e}\sin(pr).
$$
I have thought to some techinques using residues with Cauchy theorem and Jordan's Lemma. I would appreciate any insight about.

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the integrand is even, you can extend the integral to $(-\infty,\infty)$ and divide by $2$. Then you can split the sine up into two complex exponentials. For each of them, you can close the contour with a semicircle at infinity in one of the half-planes, and then apply the residue theorem. The denominator is biquadratic in $p$, so you can solve for $p^2$ and take both square roots of both solutions to find the four poles.